# Late binding to Outlook in Excel 2013 VBA error when file saved with Excel 2019: Missing Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Most of the machines in my premises run Office 2013. However, 1 machine runs Office 2019.

When I save an Excel file in Excel 2019 and then open it in Excel 2013, I get the error

> Missing Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library

After doing some research, I understood that I can prevent this by using late binding in my VBA code. I think that I am already using late binding.

```vb
Sub SendMailForwarderquote()
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim OutApp As Object
  Dim OutMail As Object
 
  With Application
  .EnableEvents = False
  .ScreenUpdating = False
  End With
 
  Set rng = Nothing
  On Error Resume Next
  'Only the visible cells in the selection
  Set rng = Sheets("Quote from forwarder").Range("A4:G46")
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  If rng Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected " & _
  vbNewLine & "please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
  Exit Sub
  End If
 
  Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  OutApp.Session.Logon
  Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
 
  On Error Resume Next
  With OutMail
  .To = Sheets("Quote from forwarder").Range("D11").Value
  .CC = ""
  .BCC = ""
  .Subject = Sheets("Quote from forwarder").Range("B12").Value
  .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
  '.Send
  .Display
  End With
  On Error GoTo 0
 
  With Application
  .EnableEvents = True
  .ScreenUpdating = True
  End With
 
  Set OutMail = Nothing
  Set OutApp = Nothing
  
  'MsgBox "Mail sent ", vbOKOnly, "Mail"
  
  End Sub
```

Comment: Did you remove the Word reference from your VBA project?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but seeing the error 'Missing Microsoft outlook 16.0 object library' I think that unlike Excel 2019 the CreateObject ("Outlook.Application") function on Excel 2013 still needs to have the reference.

To do this when you are in the VBA editor go to Tools-> References and checked Microsoft Office 16.0 Object Library (I don't have Excel 2013 so I don't know if that's the problem)

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]